# Check that two users are friends together in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have searched before asking, popular answer before can't help my project

Table struct

**USERS TABLE**

userid | username

```
1|user1
2|user2
3|user3
4|user4
5|user5
6|user6
```

**FRIEND TABLE**

requestuserid | targetuserid

```
1|3
1|4
1|6
3|2
3|5
2|4
2|1
```

Now ok, my problems is:

If userid **1** haved relation with userid **2** I only store in **Users** table like:

```
1|2
```

And not store duplicate like

```
1|2
2|1
```

Now I need to check user-x is friend with user-y, if two is friend php will return true, false else.
Very possible if my database stored duplicate 1|2 and 2|1, but no :(

How can I do with one query ?

Comment: So your Friend table stores friendship requests only?

Comment: @barbashov Yes, only store friendship request

Comment: So if you only know that user 1 requested friendship to user 2, how can we know that user 2 confirmed?

Comment: @barbashov Friend table has more column like `type`, `timerequest`, `timeapply`, `type` use to store friend status, pending/friend/block :)

Comment: @LouisCLast then @Lumbendil's answer will suite your needs. Just add additional filtering for friend status, i.e. `SELECT 1 FROM friends WHERE ((requestuserid = :id1 AND targetuserid = :id2) OR (requestuserid = :id2 AND targetuserid = :id1)) AND friendstatus = 'friend'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd do it by using `OR`.

`SELECT 1 FROM friends WHERE (requestuserid = :id1 AND targetuserid = :id2) OR (requestuserid = :id2 AND targetuserid = :id1)`

This query will return an empty set on failure, and a 1 on success.

Comment: Thankyou, but query of Sheep Slapper is helpful and safer

Comment: Sorry, I have thoroughly tested back, your query is saved more resources, only replace `1` to `anything field` to add additional filtering :) Now I will check true/false by isset() and other verify method :).

Comment: How do you use same query when joining tables.

When i fetch data from some table check if it is from conformed friend.?

Answer (score 1):

This query will return a row if the users are friends (using `OR` to disregard who the target/request user is), or return nothing if they aren't friends:

```
SELECT * FROM users u1, users u2, friends f
WHERE u1.userid = ?u1 AND u2.userid=?u2
AND ((u1.userid=f.requestuserid AND u2.userid=f.targetuserid)
OR (u2.userid=f.requestuserid AND u1.userid=f.targetuserid))
```

Comment: Since there is no join with tables users u1 and users u2, wouldn't this return a lot of rows if the condition matched? Also, he didn't say he needed to fetch user information aswell.

Comment: You caught me mid edit, adding the filter down to JUST those 2 user ids. If you *only* need to know that they friends or not, it's too much data. Mine will also return all the user data, which might be overkill

Comment: Now it seems it'd be safe to use, though I prefer to avoid usage of * unless I'm in the console testing a query, since you don't know what it'll return, so I prefer to list all the fields.